# Draggable, Droppable, and Clone

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm trying to make a "picture palette", where you have a bunch of images and can drag & drop them to replace the image in a particular div.

Drag works, the drop event registers, but the passed `ui` object doesn't seem to contain a clone of the dragged image as expected.  What's wrong?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9g4j/5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui.helper` is an array with 1 element. Console logging is an excellent feature that helps debug javascript. You need to either have Chrome, or Firefox with "Developer Tools" plugin installed.

```
console.log(ui.helper);
```

Outputs:

```
[<img src=​"http:​/​/​jsfiddle.net/​img/​logo.png" class=​"ui-draggable" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 1px;​ top:​ 28px;​ opacity:​ 1;​ ">​]
```

Comment: You're right, it does indeed contain the image element as I expected.  I wonder if I'm misunderstanding the documentation...